# Error when running simple Shell (.sh) script

Tags: raspbian

So I'm trying to run a simple shell script as seen below but I'm facing an error also seen below. 
I've added permissions and everything to the file so, in theory, it should be working?
Shell,

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello Stack"
```

Error

[image]

As seen this is located in my user profile (./home/pi/) if anyone has any idea why this mightn't be working please do share :) thanks in advance.

## UPDATE

Thanks, everyone for the suggestions, I have changed the name of the file to simply test.sh and gave this another shot. In the photo below you can see the contents of test.sh as well as the location and my attempts at giving permission to and running the file. I'm totally lost to why this isn't working? 
[image]

Comment: How do you start the script? Are you sure it's in ~/ ?

Comment: it looks like you have a space in the filename try renaming the file - to remove the space. If that does not work please edit your question and include the answer to Dirk's question and the output of ls -la.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I have updated the post answering Dirk's question and I have renamed the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several possibilities, the most likely of which are covered by @SteveRobillard and @Dirk in their comments. I'll throw in a couple of more to try to cover all possibilities:

1. the file must be in your path; if you're logged in as user `pi` you can use this from wherever you are in the file system: `~/"hello world.sh"`
2. if there's actually a space in your file `hello world.sh`, you will need to put that in quotes: `~/"hello world.sh"` . Alternatively, you can rename the file, e.g. `mv ~/"hello world.sh" ~/helloworld.sh`
3. I know you said you've set permissions, but just for good measure: `chmod 755 ~/"hello world.sh"` (or `chmod 755 ~/helloworld.sh` if that's your file name)
4. if you connect to your pi through an SSH connection from another host, make sure the SSH connection is actually up when you enter the command; in other words, are you commanding your remote host to run this command, or are you commanding your RPi to run this command? (i do this all the time! :P )

ADDITION:

I should have thought of this, but didn't until the question was edited :)

5. If you've created your script file on a Windows machine, then ***transferred*** it to your RPi, that will be a problem [**see note 1**]. You may see a mysterious error message with `^M` in it. This is because Windows uses an additional  "line control" character. You don't see it because it's hidden... [here's an explanation](https://danielmiessler.com/study/crlf/). There are several solutions to this, but in this case, the easiest is just to re-create the file in the editor on your Raspberry Pi (or another Unix machine, or even a Mac). RPi has a very easy-to-use editor called `nano`; you start it from the command line by typing `nano`  :)

   For a larger file, or if you want/need to edit your files in Windows for some reason, another solution is to install `dos2unix` on your RPi as follows:

   `sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade
    sudo apt-get install dos2unix`

   Then, once you have transferred your file from Windows to your RPi, run this command:

   `dos2unix test.sh`  (or whatever your file name is, if it's not test.sh)

This will purge the pesky [`carriage return` `<CR>`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) from your script, and your shell won't be confused by it any longer.

**note 1. "transferred" means that you have transferred it as a file, or you have "copied-and-pasted" it from Windows to *nix. That pesky `carriage return` will not simply disappear!**

Comment: Also, make sure the first line in the script ends in a linefeed without any preceding carriage return.  The CR is hard to see if you don't know how to look for it, and can lead to a "bad interpreter: no such file or directory" message when spawned directly from bash; it's possible a GUI launching it will only generate the latter part of the error.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I have updated the post attempting everything you suggested but yet still no success?

Comment: @CharlieSimon: Yes, I omitted a possibility, but have addressed it in my edited answer. To summarize, don't create shell scripts in Windows, then transfer them to your RPi to run; create and edit the shell script on your RPi using `nano`.

Comment: @MontyHarder: Good catch... you saw that coming  :)

Comment: @Seamus I feel bad now that this isn't working but I did make the file on the PI... I used copy and paste if that means anything but I didn't import an already created file over to my PI. Possibly if I just run an update or something?

Comment: @CharlieSimon: Yes, that (copy and paste) means something. Please try one of the solutions I've recommended (***create*** on RPi, or install & run `dos2unix`). It will work.

Comment: @CharlieSimon: I've edited the answer again to address the C&P aspect of this... and thanks for pointing this out! Once you "know" something, it becomes easy to forget that, at one time, you didn't know it  :)

Comment: @Seamus Long experience in having to transfer files between DOS/Windows and *nix has taught me to look for that particular error, and even before the OP put in the screenshot to confirm it's the ^M, it's the very first thing I think of in such situations.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an addition to Seamus's excellent answer, as you clearly have a space in the file name, what is happening when you call it using

```
hello world.sh
```

or

```
./home/pi/hello world.sh
```

is that the shell attempts to execute the file `./home/pi/hello` and presumes that `world.sh` is an intended argument to be passed to the `hello` executable.

Obviously, this is not the case, the `./home/pi/hello` executable can not be found and hence the error message

Answer (score 1):

The command shell, bash in this case, is reacting to the space.

You can run the command if you escape the space:

~/hello\ world.sh

works for me.

Without escaping the space I get the same error message as you did.

Comment: The esc char is a good trick; for some reason I never think of using it in a shell command.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a shell file in the current directory say Ex4.sh
(Let's assume it contains the shebang and have used chmod +x Ex4.sh)
Well:
Ex4.sh
Does not work.
But
./Ex4.sch
Does work.
Here "./" indicate in the current directory.
Why is this necessary?
Who knows: I'm a beginner.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/122373)